# How to connect to a SQL CE database from JavaScript running in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I am developing a Browser Plugin for which I am storing data locally in SQLCE Database .
But I have to display saved data in browser in form of a webpage , for this my webpage needs to connect to local database and fetch the values . I am planning to use javascript to do the same . But haven't got any success till now .
Can anyone point me to the right direction whether it is possible or if not possible any other 
way I can do that .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a SQLCE database from JavaScript, but you can publish it through OData protocol using ASP.NET WebAPI or WCF Data Services.
If you use IE10 (that supports EcmaScript5) you can follow [this tutorial](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-create-a-synchronized-online-offline-data-application-with-entityframework%E2%80%93-the-online-data-service)

Comment: Are you sure this method will work for a desktop application .I can't host anything on a server .

Answer (score 0):

you cannot connect dirctly from javascrip

but you can make a [web method] in asp connect to your database
and you can call this method from java scrip by ajax call

ex:

in cs file :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string myMethod(long ID)
{
    ////you can in method to connect to any database 
    return _result;
}
```

in javascript file :

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mypage.aspx/myMethod",
            data: "{ID:'" + ID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(result) {

            }
    , error: function(error) {

    }
        });
```

Comment: It's a desktop application so I can't use ASP .